# How to handle Strict Transport Security (HSTS) using JMeter Recording

Tags: jmeter, recording, hsts

I would like to know another possebility to bypass this except flood.io. This is what I get. Last time I tried this, the page couldt be exported to .har in a proper way.

- [JMeter 2.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCCPd.png)
- [FF v44](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seLe1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Blazemeter (makers of JMeter) now have an online conversion tool:
[converter.blazemeter.com](http://converter.blazemeter.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with one of the internal sites I am testing with.

Jmeter Recording worked for Firefox, but not for Chrome.

Then I found this page: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/

To Summarize, you'll need to navigate to that browser's HSTS settings page. e.g. chrome://net-internals/#hsts

Then Query that domain to see if it really is an HSTS issue.

Finally, delete that domain from the HSTS entry list.

It didn't work for me until I reopened my browser, but now I'm able to record a script through my app, whereas I couldn't even get to the login page before in Chrome.